# ¿Es posible usar Laravel Dusk junto a Behat en un proyecto de Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5, pruebas-unitarias, behat

Estoy usando laravel 5.5 y quisiera saber si puedo integrar Behat en el mismo y usar las funcionalidades de Dusk en el archivo FeatureContext generado por Behat, donde se crean las características de mis pruebas como funciones de la clase. En este caso sería extender la clase FeatureContext de DuskTestCase.

Comment: Y cua seria el problema de utilizar phpunit??? porque behat?

Comment: Estoy en ultimo año de Ingeneria Informatica y me exigen usar behat en mi tesis. He usado Phpunit en otras ocasiones, pero como es obligatorio aqui estoy